# How to write a C program to calculate total amount of money?

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a program  that asks the user to input the number of coins that the user has and then output the total amount of money the user has. So it will be that the user has dimes, nickels, pennies and quarters only.  After the user enters the number of coins for each denomination, the program should output the total amount of money.

```
    #include "Coins Project.h"
    #include <stdio.h>
 
    int change(float total, int *quarters, int *dimes, int *nickels, int 
    *pennies);
    void print(float total, int quarters, int dimes, int nickels, int 
    pennies);
 
    int main(void)
    {
    int quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies;
    float total;
 
    total = 1.88;
    change(total, &quarters, &dimes, &nickels, &pennies);
    print(total, quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies);
 
    total = 0.32;
    change(total, &quarters, &dimes, &nickels, &pennies);
    print(total, quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies);
 
    printf("\nPlease enter an amount of money: \n");
    scanf("%f", &total);
 
    change(total, &quarters, &dimes, &nickels, &pennies);
    print(total, quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies);
 
    return 0;
    }
 
    int change(float total, int *quarters, int *dimes, int *nickels, int 
    *pennies)
    {
    if( total >= 0.25 )
        *quarters = (total / 0.25);
    if( total >= 0.10 )
        *dimes = (total - (*quarters * 0.25)) / 0.10;
    if( total >= 0.05 )
        *nickels = (total - (*quarters * 0.25) - (*dimes * 0.10)) / 
    0.05;
    if( total >= 0.01 )
        *pennies = (total - (*quarters * 0.25) - (*dimes * 0.10) - 
    (*nickels * 0.05)) / 0.01 + .005;
 
    return 0;
    }
 
    void print(float total, int quarters, int dimes, int nickels, int 
    pennies)
    {
    printf("\nTOTAL VALUE ENTERED: $%.2f", total);
    printf("\n%3d quarters\n", quarters);
    printf("\n%3d dimes\n", dimes);
    printf("\n%3d nickels\n", nickels);
    printf("\n%3d pennies\n", pennies);
    }
```

The code should work for any coins entered by the user and should show the total at the end.

Comment: so what's the problem?

Comment: Your algorithm in `change` looks very convoluted. Why not just add the partial cent sums of each coin type together to get the total sum? Then you can divide the total sum by 100 to convert to dollars if you want.... or maybe I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Your problem description sounds like you want to sum up all the coins to get the total amount of money, but your code looks like you're trying to make change based on a total amount of money ..?

Comment: Yeah I'm confused. Its supposed to work like this .                                            
 How many pennies do you have? 10

You entered 10

How many nickels do you have? 5

You entered 5

How many dimes do you have? 1

You entered 1

How many quarters do you have? 1

You entered 1

You have $0.70

Thank you.

Comment: Be sure to initialize all your local variables otherwise you can get some garbage output.  For example if total is 0.20 then quarters will never be set.

Comment: yeah in that case, just add them all up: `total = (25 * quarters) + (10 * dimes) + ( 5 * nickles) + pennies;` That will give you the total change in cents, you can divide by 100 and cast to `float` if you want to display it in dollars. There's no reason to initialize `total` to some random value. But the code you have doesn't reflect this at all. It looks like you're trying to make change from a total, ie, the user enters 32 cents for the total, and your program says this is 1 quarter, 1 nickel, 2 pennies.

Answer (score 2):

If you just simply want to give the number of coins to the program in one go you can just do this:

```
scanf("%d %d %d %d", &quarters, &dimes, &nickels, &pennies);
```

Comment: int main()

{
    float a = 0.01;
    float b = 0.05;
    float c = 0.10;
    float d = 0.25;
    
    return 0;

    printf("How many pennies?");
    scanf("%f", &a);
    printf("How many nickels?");
    scanf("%f", &b);
    printf("How many dimes?");
    scanf("%f", &c);
    printf("How many quarters?");
    scanf("%f", &d);
    printf("You have $ %f\n", (a+b+c+d));
    
    return 0;
}

I re did it like this but im still having a problem

Comment: what is the problem?